# Working with exe files in c

Tags: c, windows, file, exe, portable-executable

(Working on Windows 8)
I'm trying to get the size of section headers in an exe file (PE32 Format) with c.
From what I read, the offset from this field is 60 so I tried reading from there.

This is the code I used:

```
unsigned char offset;
fseek(file, 60, SEEK_SET);
fread(&offset, sizeof(offset), 1, file);
printf("%hu", offset);
```

My Question is how can i get the size of the section headers? if its not on offset 60, how can i find this?

Comment: You have to remember that `.exe` files are *binary* files, and the data in them is *not* strings.

Comment: Scanning with `%s` scans until it hits a null bit (`\0`) which means it kept scanning until it exceeded 20 characters. Perhaps `%c%c` would've scanned the first 2 bytes only.

Comment: I have opened the file with "rb" and I didnt see any different way to read binary files

Comment: What do you mean when you say "exe files"? There's COM, PE32, ELF, Hunk, ... -- and for most of them, there's libraries for reading their metadata. At least flag your question so that we know which *operating system* you are working on... Also, this smells like an XY problem. What do you need the section header size *for*? This is stuff that usually only advanced programmers bother with, and if you were one of them, you wouldn't have posted this question...

Comment: Im taking a class and for a few lessons now we are studying about operating system, now we got to exe formats, and to finish my homework this is one of the questions, to get the number of sections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
void main()
{
  FILE *file = fopen("your_exe_file.exe", "rb") ;

  long peheaderoffset ;
  // read the offset of the PE header which is located at offset 0x3c
  fseek(file, 0x3c, SEEK_SET) ;
  fread(&peheaderoffset, sizeof(long), 1, file) ;

  char PEHeader[4] ;  // PE header: contains normally 'P','E',0,0
  fseek(file, peheaderoffset, SEEK_SET) ;
  fread(&PEHeader, 4, 1, file) ;

  short machine ;
  short NumberofSections ;

  fread(&machine, sizeof(short), 1, file) ;  // read machine identifier
  fread(&NumberofSections, sizeof(short), 1, file) ;  // read Number of sections

  printf ("PE Header = %s\n", PEHeader) ; // should always print "PE"
                                          // we should check if PEHEeader actually
                                          // contains "PE". If not it's not a PE file
  printf ("machine = %x\n", machine) ;    // 14c for Intel x86
  printf ("Number of sections = %d\n", NumberofSections) ; 

  // skip to size of optional header
  fseek(file, 12, SEEK_CUR) ;

  short SizeOfOptionalHeader ;
  fread (&SizeOfOptionalHeader, sizeof(short), 1, file) ;
  printf ("Sizeof optional PE header = %d\n", SizeOfOptionalHeader) ;  

  short characteristics ;
  fread (&characteristics, sizeof(short), 1, file) ;
  printf ("Characteristics = %x\n", characteristics) ;  

  // now we are at the PE optional header
  short signature ;
  fread (&signature, sizeof(short), 1, file) ;
  printf ("Signature of optioan PE Header = %d (should be 267)\n", signature) ;  

  // skip to image Base at offset 0x1c
  // (the -2 is because we have already read the signature just above)
  fseek(file, 0x1c - 2, SEEK_CUR) ;
  long imageBase ;
  fread (&imageBase, sizeof(long), 1, file) ;
  printf ("Image base = %x\n", imageBase) ;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly, now I will try the use of peheaderoffset :-)

Comment: I need more rep for that but i will remember to vote once i get that, Thank you very much!
Do you know if the imgBase field which is located in 0x1c is just pointing to where the real address is or the add is there? i just get 0 when i try to read this field

Comment: @Yarden: what do you mean by "imgBase field which is located in 0x1c" ?

Comment: @Yarden: OK, I thing I've got what you mean by ImgBase. I updated the code. The offset 0x1c you are refering to is the offset from the beginning of the optional PE header. All the information you need is actually [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files#MS-DOS_EXE_Files).

Answer (score 0):

try using fread instead of fscanf, and (as Joachim) pointed out it's a binary file, so make sure you've opened the file in binary mode (file=fopen (filename, "rb"))

Answer (score 0):

The field you are trying to read is 4 bytes long, but you are trying to read a NULL terminated string from there. You probably got the right value, but then you print it as if it was a printable string (maybe you were expecting something like "216" or "D8" to be printed, but strings such as these are not what is stored).

Printable strings contains a sequence of codes, each representing a character (in ASCII, at least), followed by a '\0' terminator. This is what "%s" scanf/printf formatting option deals with. But that is not how data is usually stored in binary files. You may try this to get the number you want:

```
unsigned int offset;
fseek(file, 60, SEEK_SET);
fread(&offset, sizeof(offset), 1, file);
printf("%u", offset);
```

Probably the best name to use would be `uint32_t`, but that would require from you to include `<inttype.h>` to work.

Comment: fscanf() will expect ASCII data such as "255", but what is needed is to read a single byte as a "small integer".  You need to use fread() .

Answer (score 0):

fscanf() is inappropriate - it reads ASCII data, while the PE32 is a binary format - you want to read a single 32bit integer, not a numeric string (similarly for printing "%s" is an inappropriate format specifier.

You also have to be sure to open the file in binary mode, otherwise and  sequence will be translated to a single  and `fseek()` will not work as expected.

```
uint32_t sizeOfHeaders = 0 ;
FILE* file = fopen( filename, "rb" ) ; // Open in binary mode
fseek( file, 60, SEEK_SET ) ;
fread( &sizeOfHeaders, sizeof(sizeOfHeaders), 1, file ) ;
printf("%u", sizeOfHeaders ) ;
```

Comment: The size of the section headers field should be 2 bytes, so how will I handle that?

Comment: `unsigned short offset;` to declare, `fread(&offset, sizeof(offset), 1, file);` to read, and `"%hu"` to print.

Comment: @Yarden:  I've just looked at Microsoft's documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx, and it is in fact 4 bytes. I was trusting lvella's answer.  Fixing right now.

Comment: Well, I had fully disclaimed that it could be any size :)

Comment: @lvella : ... and the question has been edited several times causing further confusion.

Comment: I will try to be more organized in the future im sorry about the cnfusion